# In how many ways a natural number $n$ can be product of $3$ natural numbers greater than $1$?

Tags: combinatorics

For example, let $n=16$, then $16=2\times2\times4$ works but $16=4\times4\times1$ doesn't, and for $n=3$ there are no solutions.

Comment: Hint: look at the prime decomposition of $n$

Comment: What have you tried?  to get started, I'd suggest working with the prime factorization. If $n=\prod p_i^{a_i}$.  Then we need to split, say, $p_1^{a_1}$ into the three factors.  Thats a Stars and Bars question.  Then you have to exclude symmetries and ensure that no terms is $1$.

Comment: Does $2\times4\times2$ count as a different solution?

Comment: @J.G. No, it does not matter and count

Comment: @lulu could you explain it more please?

Comment: Please edit your post to include your efforts.  I think my hint was self explanatory...to handle the case $n=p^a$ we have to write $a=b+c+d$ in distinct integers. That is a Stars and Bars problem.   It gets somewhat more complicated if you have multiple primes since you don't need all the primes to be split into distinct terms, you just need to consider cases in which two or more terms coincide.